# Ecology and Ecologism

Tags: discussion

There is an Area51 Proposal [Ecology and Ecologism](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/120992/ecology-and-ecologism) I think several of the questions there potentially work here.

The proposal is approaching failure (a couple of days before it gets closed)

Some of us may want to stop by and post a comment on questions that would work here, directing the poster to us.

Comment: Hi James! That proposal closed on April 22nd. The example questions are still visible, and I notice you kindly pointed some of those folks here. I personally don't see anything else that's on-topic here, but maybe other people will. This is a good idea, and a reminder to check Area51 once in a while for that purpose.